# scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor scrape Master and Detail pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract information from Listing and Detail pages.
The code below correctly scrapes the reviewer information from the Listing page and all linked pages (where a contains Next)
The detail_pages Urls are also captured. e.g. http://www.screwfix.com/p/prysmian-6242y-twin-earth-cable-2-5mm-x-100m-grey/20967

However I cannot see how I can navigate to and scrape the information from the Detail pages.

Is there anyone here who used Scrapy successfully who can help me to finish this spider?

Thank you for the help.

I include the code for the spider below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from hn_scraper.items import HnArticleItem


class ScrewfixSpider(Spider):
    name = "Screwfix"
    allowed_domains = ["www.screwfix.com"]
    start_urls = ('http://www.screwfix.com/', )

    link_extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor(
        allow=('www', ),
        restrict_xpaths=('//a[contains(., "Next")]', ))

    detail_page_extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor(
        allow=('www', ), 
        restrict_xpaths=('//tr[@id[contains(., "reviewer")]]/td[3]/a', ))

    def extract_one(self, selector, xpath, default=None):
        extracted = selector.xpath(xpath).extract()
        if extracted:
            return extracted[0]
        return default

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in self.link_extractor.extract_links(response):
            request = Request(url=link.url)
            request.meta.update(link_text=link.text)
            yield request

        for item in self.parse_item(response):
            yield item


    def parse_item(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)

        rows = selector.xpath('//table[contains(.,"crDataGrid")]//tr[@id[contains(., "reviewer")]]')
        for row in rows:
            item = HnArticleItem()

            reviewer = row.xpath('td[3]/a')                     
            reviewer_url = self.extract_one(reviewer, './@href', '')
            reviewer_name = self.extract_one(reviewer, 'b/text()', '')
            total_reviews = row.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract()

            item['url'] = reviewer_url
            item['name'] = reviewer_name
            item['total_reviews'] = total_reviews       

            yield item


        detail_pages = self.detail_page_extractor.extract_links(response)

        if detail_pages:

            print 'detail_pages'
            print detail_pages[0].url

            yield Request(detail_pages[0].url)
```

Comment: What about navigating to element of product description? XPath = `//*[@id='product_specification_list']`?